# Question about integrating a small dF force to find total force F

Tags: electromagnetism, integration

I don't want to ask about the force specifically. I'll take the force as an example.

Let's say we have a magnetic force  $$\vec F=q(\vec u\times\vec B)$$ and we are inside a cylindrical conductor carrying a current I. The B field is the one created by the conductor. How should I write $d\vec f$? Does d go everywhere? like : $dq(du\times dB)$? And if not how do I know the terms that have d in front? Right here B is changing inside the conductor , so it could be dB. Current changes so dq and du makes sense. Now trying to find dB there are other variables. Do they all get a d? Let's say I write everything in terms of $dq$. I'll get 3 $dq$s from , one from $q$, one from $u$ and one from $B$ That gives $d^3q$ which seems wrong.

I need to find $dF$ in order to integrate . I have the same problem when I need to find an electric field for example(dE). How do I find what variable I'm integrating over?

Comment: it is unclear to me what you really want but in general you can write that if $\vec{F} = q(\vec{v} \times \vec{B})$ then the differential force element is $d\vec{F} = dq(\vec{v} \times \vec{B})+q(d\vec{v} \times \vec{B})+q(\vec{v} \times d\vec{B})$. If charge is constant, that is $dq=0$, then the 1st term is missing from the sum, if the velocity is constant, $\vec{v}=0$ then the 2nd term is missing, etc.

Comment: One more thing. This is the B field inside a cylindrical conductor for a distance r smaller than the radius R  $ B=\frac{μIr}{2πR^2} $. What is the differential element for this if everything is a constant except for r ? Will it be the same with $dr$ instead of $r$ or will it be with $r+dr$ ? I've been studying for hours , my mind is far from clear right now .

Comment: If $B=\frac{\mu I r}{2\pi R^2}$ then $dB = \frac{\mu r }{2\pi R^2}dI+\frac{\mu I }{2\pi R^2}dr+\frac{\mu I r}{2\pi} d(\frac1{ R^2})$, where $d(\frac1{ R^2}) = -\frac{2}{ R^3} dR$. Now set $dI=0$ and $dR=0$.